# Using Mongodb with Firebase/Firestore

Tags: mongodb, firebase, nosql, google-cloud-firestore

I am considering using Firebase/Firestore and Mongodb together for data storage. The idea is to use Firebase to store data that users will interact with on mobile and use MongoDB for more backend stuff or web content that won't be accessible on the app.

I've found a lot of people switching between the two, but very few topics discuss using both. Is there any reasons why this isn't done more often?

Comment: My personal view is that it's easier to keep all of your data in one place, rather than fragment it between different databases, unless you have a particular need to do so (for example, full text search in Elasticsearch / Algolia).  You can build rules to restrict who can access which data and it also means that you can easily create static web pages, rather than a backend which builds the pages and delivers only HTML.  Cloud Firestore is a distributed, highly available datastore.  Using MongoDB requires you to manage clusters, services, etc.  A headache that I prefer to be without